# Does Drupal 7 "CiviCRM Entity" online event registration generate confirmation email?

Tags: civicrm-entity, online-registration, drupal-7

I just started using CiviCRM Entity to embed event registration forms in my Drupal 7 web pages.  The event registration works, but people who register through this mechanism do not receive registration confirmation emails.  If I use the standard CiviCRM full-screen event registration form, then I do get a confirmation email.

Does the Drupal 7 CiviCRM Entity module online event registration support sending confirmation emails?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you used the Price Set Entity field to get the registration form.

The confirmation email was never fleshed out totally.

There are also 2 Rules Events you can react to:
"Event Registration" and "Successful CC Transaction"
Which then you could use Drupal's stock "Send email" action ...

We do have a Rules action, "Send Contribution API sendconfirmation" .. which does what it says .. for the contribution created, it runs the Contribution API entity, "sendconfirmation" action ..
Which is ok unless there is no contribution.

We'd also done some things where we implement hook_form_alter() and add a submit handler ..and programmatically send an email on form submission.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Yes, I'm using the Price Set Entity field.  So "never fleshed out totally" means their is no code to send the confirmation, correct?  Or is there something somewhere that perhaps I could use to make my own?  It would be nice if this was listed as a limitation in the module description.  I don't think the rules system will include the event detail information provided in the standard event registration confirmation email.

Comment: That's what's missing, is the event detail. With the current Rules action you can send a contribution receipt. Or you can programmatically generate the email with a custom submit handler and a hook_mail() implementation, per Drupal norms. There's always a limitation to software, people always want more for free.